# Time difference and summation between multiple rows on change

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a code that can do the following :

1. Calculates time difference (in HH:MM format) between two `type="time"` elements on a row.
2. Sum the total difference (in HH:MM format) in text input.

I've managed to create a function fired by the `onchange` event, but my function is only considering the first values entered, meaning that when you update the timings, the difference will be recalculated and the total will be wrong.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my JavaScript code for calculating the first line:

```
function CalTime0() {
    var timeOfCall = $('#timefrom0').val(),
    timeOfResponse = $('#timeto0').val(),
    hours = timeOfResponse.split(':')[0] - timeOfCall.split(':')[0],
    minutes = timeOfResponse.split(':')[1] - timeOfCall.split(':')[1],
    total = $('#tbtotal').val(),
    tothours = total.split(':')[0],
    totminutes = total.split(':')[1];               
    minutes = minutes.toString().length<2?'0'+minutes:minutes;
    totminutes = totminutes.toString().length<2?'0'+totminutes:totminutes;

    if(minutes<0) { 
        hours--;
        minutes = 60 + minutes;
    }

    hours = hours.toString().length<2?'0'+hours:hours;
    tothours = tothours.toString().length<2?'0'+tothours:tothours;
    tothours = parseInt(tothours) + parseInt(hours);
    totminutes = parseInt(totminutes) + parseInt(minutes);

    if(totminutes >= 60) { 
        tothours++;
        totminutes = totminutes - 60;
    }

    $('#total0').val(hours + ':' + minutes);    
    $('#tbtotal').val(tothours + ':' + totminutes); 
}
```

Comment: Please spend some time to get the right indentation for your code if you post something on SO. Correctly indented code is much easier to read.

Comment: I just indented your code; it looks like a chunk of it is missing. I don't think this will run.

Comment: thanks for that @Sumurai8 ,i did revise the code.

Comment: Can't you just substract the value that is orriginally in `#total0`?

Comment: if have 10 rows,and for each row i am using a different function,so your suggest is add more function that picks the current value and updated it?

Comment: ??? I thought the problem was that if you updated one of #totalfrom0 or #totalto0, #tbtotal is incorrect?

Comment: yes,because the current situation,function will update #tbtotal with the first value difference, but if you update #totalfrom0 and #totalto0 , the function will add the updated value to the current value of #tbtotal.
in the same time,i need the last logic to sum the other lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to substract the time the `#total0` field represents from the time the `#tbtotal` field represents. Then you calculate the new `#total0` field, and add that time to `#tbtotal` again. This way the time displayed in `#tbtotal` is always correct.

The other question seemed to be how to do this for all rows, instead of just this one. You can use the `this` keyword to figure out what element fired the change event. From there you can figure out what the other elements would be. For this purpose I renamed the fields to `timefr0` and `timeto0`, so they are equal length.

I took the liberty to convert all times to seconds, and manipulate them that way. The comments in the script should speak for themselfs.

```
function updateTotals() {
  //Get num part of the id from current set
  //Cheated a bit with the id names ;-)
  var num = $(this).attr('id').substr( 6 );

  //Get the time from each and every one of them
  var tfrom = $('#timefr' + num ).val().split(':');
  var tto = $('#timeto' + num ).val().split(':');
  var currtotal = $('#total' + num ).val().split(':');
  var grandtotal = $('#tbtotal').val().split(':');

  //Convert to seconds and do the calculations the easy way
  var diff = (tto[0] - tfrom[0]) * 3600 + (tto[1] - tfrom[1]) * 60;
  var totalsec = currtotal[0] * 3600 + currtotal[1] * 60;
  var grandtotalsec = grandtotal[0] * 3600 + grandtotal[1] * 60;

  //If the result is negative, we can't do anything sensible. Use 0 instead.
  if( diff < 0 ) {
    diff = 0;
  }

  //Substract what we calculated last time
  grandtotalsec -= totalsec;
  //Then add the current diff
  grandtotalsec += diff;

  //Convert diff (or total) into human readable form
  var hours = Math.floor( diff / 3600 );
  diff = diff % 3600;
  var minutes = Math.floor( diff / 60 );

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours.toString() : hours.toString();
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes.toString() : minutes.toString();


  //Convert grandtotal into human readable form
  var grandtotalhours = Math.floor( grandtotalsec / 3600 );
  grandtotalsec = grandtotalsec % 3600;
  var grandtotalminutes = Math.floor( grandtotalsec / 60 );

  grandtotalhours = (grandtotalhours < 10) ? "0" + grandtotalhours.toString() : grandtotalhours.toString();
  grandtotalminutes = (grandtotalminutes < 10) ? "0" + grandtotalminutes.toString() : grandtotalminutes.toString();  

  //Put them in the fields
  $( '#total' + num ).val( hours + ":" + minutes );
  $( '#tbtotal' ).val( grandtotalhours + ":" + grandtotalminutes );
}
```

An example fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rrtY5/).

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, to compute date differences more easily, use moment.js. The date difference computation should be replaceable by something like this, with moment:

```
moment(timeOfResponse).diff(moment(timeOfCall))
```

moment.js diff documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/